# Is there a simple way to toggle a javascript variable between true and false ?

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
    modalTogglePreview: function ($scope) {
        if ($scope.modal.wmdPreview === true) {
            $scope.modal.wmdPreview = false;
        } else {
            $scope.modal.wmdPreview = true;
        }
    }
```

Is there some way I could achieve the same but without the if statement ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$scope.modal.wmdPreview = !$scope.modal.wmdPreview;
```

The unary `!` operator interprets its argument as boolean, and returns the boolean complement. Note that this really isn't *exactly* the same as your code: yours only works if the variable is *exactly* `true` when it's tested. In my experience (for what that's worth), relying on variables used as flags in JavaScript to be real booleans is a little fragile. (There are counter-arguments however, so it's up to you.)

To explain further, the `!` operator will interpret the values `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `false`, and the empty string `""` as being `false`.  Any other value is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using the not operator as Pointy mentioned (which should be the preferred way), if you find yourself setting a boolean value inside an `if...else` statement, then you are likely doing something wrong.
The condition is already evaluated to a boolean value. So your `if...else` statement is equivalent to

```
$scope.modal.wmdPreview = $scope.modal.wmdPreview !== true;
```

---

Have a look at these examples:

```
var result;

if (cond) {
    result = true;
}
else {
   result = false;
}
```

This means, if the condition (`cond`) is true, set `result` to `true`. If `cond` is false,  set result to `false`. The value we assign to `result` is exactly the value of `cond`. Hence the above is equivalent to writing

```
var result = cond;
```

Now, sometimes we use conditions that don't evaluate to a boolean. To convert any value to its boolean equivalent, you can apply the not operator *twice*:

```
var result = !!cond;
```

Similar for the other way round:

```
var result;

if (cond) {
   result = false;
}
else {
   result = true;
}
```

If `cond` is true, assign `false` to `result`. If `cond` is false, assign `true` to `result`. This is the same as in your situation. The value we assign to `result` is the opposite of the value of `cond`. As Pointy showed, we can use the not operator for this:

```
var result = !cond;
```

This works with every condition, but depending on the expression, it can make it harder to read. For example, `!(x > 5)` is not as obvious as `x <= 5`. So if you find yourself in such a situation, you can usually flip the comparison operator.